# ordering sql table based on highest number of a piece of data

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I have a phpmyadmin table called comments, with fields post_id, username, title, message, location, filename, and filename1. I would like to sort the table with comments with most number of the string "filename1" at the top, and the comments with the least number of the same "filename1" to be towards the bottom. What sql code should I enter into the table to achieve this? Or what piece of code in an android application should I add to achieve this, I can edit the post with android code if necessary.

SELECT `post_id`, `username`, `title`, `message`, `location`, `filename`, `filename1` FROM `comments` WHERE 1

Comment: (1) Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you mean by "least number of the same "filename1".  (2) Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: I am using a mysql server, I will update the question now as well.

Comment: I would like to sort the table with comments with most number of the string "filename1" at the top, and the comments with the least number of the same "filename1" to be towards the bottom. 

WHAT DO  YOU MEAN?

Comment: @OzanKurt For example if there were 3 comments with the string "San Francisco" vs. two strings with "Los Angeles", I would like the comments with the "San Francisco" string to be at the top and the comments with the "Los Angeles" string to be at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "most number of string filename1", you mean you want to count the number of occurrences (duplicates) of a particular value of the `filename1` column, without regard to which post the comment is associated with...

We'd get the "count" of occurrences with a separate query, and then include that query as a rowsource (as an inline view) in the original query.

For example:

```
SELECT t.post_id
     , t.username
     , t.title
     , t.message
     , t.location
     , t.filename
     , t.filename1 
  FROM comments t 
  JOIN ( SELECT s.filename1
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM comments s
          GROUP BY s.filename1
       ) c
    ON c.filename1 = t.filename1
 WHERE 1
 ORDER
    BY c.cnt DESC
     , c.filename1 DESC
     , t.post_id DESC
```

If you wanted count of duplicate `filename1` values associated with each post, then we'd add `s.post_id` to the SELECT list and the GROUP BY clause of the inline view, and add an equality predicate on the outer query `AND c.post_id = t.post_id`.

(Without an example, it's not clear what result set you want returned, so we're just guessing.)

(Note that the equality comparator in the JOIN predicate will filter out rows that have a `NULL` value for `filename1`. If we also want to include `NULL` values, then we could replace the equality comparator with the null-safe equality comparator:

```
    ON c.filename1 <=> t.filename1
```

Comment: thanks so much man, I apologize for phrasing the question in a difficult way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the table with most number of words/strings in the field `filename1`.
for example:- "hello how r u?" will be at the top and "hello" will be at bottom.

then use this code:

```
SELECT post_id, username, title, message, location, filename, filename1 FROM comments ORDER BY (LENGTH(filename1) - LENGTH(REPLACE(filename1, ' ', ''))+1) DESC
```